# How to transform list into object based on some conditions using collect?

Tags: java-8, java-stream, collectors

I want to know if there is way in *.toCollect* method of streams to transform a list to object as per some conditions. Here is my code.
Request class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class ERequest {
    private String id;
    private String cId;
    private int pid;
    private String ind;
}
```

Response class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class ExpectedResponse {
    private String data1;
    private String data2;
    private String data3;
    
}
```

Method

```
public ExpectedResponse getPref(List<ERequest> request) {
        ExpectedResponse expectedResponse = ExpectedResponse.builder().build();

        Predicate<ERequest> isE = p -> (p.getCId().equals("ab")) && (p.getPid() == 1);
        Predicate<ERequest> isS = p -> (p.getCId().equals("cd")) && (p.getPid() == 2);
        Predicate<ERequest> isP = p -> (p.getCId().equals("ef")) && (p.getPid() == 4);

        List<ERequest> res = request.stream()
                .filter(isE.or(isS).or(isP))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        for (ERequest r : res) {
            if (r.getCId().equals("ab")) {
                expectedResponse.setData1(r.getInd());
            }
            if (r.getCId().equals("cd")) {
                expectedResponse.setData2(r.getInd());
            }
            if (r.getCId().equals("ef")) {
                expectedResponse.setData3(r.getInd());
            }
        }
        return expectedResponse;
    }
```

I'm getting a valid/required list in *res*, but I still have to use for loop to go over that list and extract data according to few conditions and then populate *ExpectedResponse*. How can I directly transform *request* into *ExpectedResponse* ?

Comment: `public ExpectedResponse getPref(List<ERequest> request) {  ExpectedResponse expectedResponse = ExpectedResponse.builder().build();  for(ERequest r: request) { 
 switch(r.getPid()) {  case 1: if (r.getCId().equals("ab")) expectedResponse.setData1(r.getInd()); break;  case 2: if (r.getCId().equals("cd")) expectedResponse.setData2(r.getInd()); break;  case 4: if (r.getCId().equals("ef")) expectedResponse.setData3(r.getInd());  }  }  return expectedResponse; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do all operations while first iteration using [filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) to filter the records and [reduce](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-), This is just an approach using `reduce` method but i haven't validated since i don't have sample data

```
 ExpectedResponse expectedResponse = requests.stream().filter(req->(req.getCId().equals("ab")) && (req.getPid() == 1) ||
            (req.getCId().equals("cd")) && (req.getPid() == 2) ||
            (req.getCId().equals("ef")) && (req.getPid() == 4))
            .reduce(ExpectedResponse.builder().build(),(response, request)->{
                if (request.getCId().equals("ab")) {
                    response.setData1(request.getInd());
                }
                if (request.getCId().equals("cd")) {
                    response.setData2(request.getInd());
                }
                if (request.getCId().equals("ef")) {
                    response.setData3(request.getInd());
                }
                return response;
            },(finalRes,finalReq)->finalRes);
```